# Regular expression to match exact number of characters?

Tags: regex

I need a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that will match any three uppercase letters, so AAA or ABC or DKE. It can't match four or more though, like AAAA or ABCDEF or aBBB.

My solution: `^([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z])$`

**Questions**:

1. Is this correct?
2. Is there another way, just for the sake of learning?

Comment: @owlstead, I did, and in fact I managed to get the right answer by myself apparently. I needed to cross check to make sure I was not wrong though, since I am new to regex.

Comment: Voted question up, but I would read the part about repetition again, because you should also know about [limiting repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

What you have is correct, but this is more consice:

```
^[A-Z]{3}$
```

Comment: Gotcha. And these two should be the only two ways, right? Yep I am sure about the uppercase.

Comment: @DanielS - With or without the capture group. Yes.

Comment: @owlstead - This is a very valid question. The OP is clearly learning, demonstrated what they're trying, and asked for guidance. The question is *very* well formed. Why would anybody close this?

Comment: @owlstead - [**No question is too trivial or too "newbie"**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9663/is-so-appropriate-for-newbish-question-about-a-specific-technology/9664#9664).

Comment: @owlstead, I also researched on SO and didn't find anything identical to my question, hence why I decided to post.

Comment: OK, the link I found was not trivial enough, and I could not find one either. No worries, removed part about uppercase chars from the answer (because of the first sentence in the question) and voted both up... My apologies.

Comment: What's the use of ^ and $ in this case?

Comment: @sunitprasad1 - `^` makes sure the pattern matches at the beginning of the string. `$` makes sure it matches at the the end of the string. Both of them together make sure that the pattern matches the entire string, ensuring that the string is no longer the pattern specified.

Comment: You can also use `^[A-Z]{3,5}$` to match between three to five uppercase letters :-)

Answer (score 26):

Your solution is correct, but there is some redundancy in your regex.

The similar result can also be obtained from the following regex:

```
^([A-Z]{3})$
```

The `{3}` indicates that the `[A-Z]` must appear exactly 3 times.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's the same answer as the previous person, however, so I'll pick his answer as the right one to be fair.

Comment: Yeah, I too noticed that after posting my answer. Well I just wanted to help, so it doesn't really matter if it is not marked as correct answer. Still thanks for commenting :)