# Select data using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['abc', 'r00001', 'r00010', 'rfoo', 'r01234', 'r1234'], 'b': range(6)})

        a  b
0     abc  0
1  r00001  1
2  r00010  2
3    rfoo  3
4  r01234  4
5   r1234  5
```

I now want to select all columns of this dataframe where the entries in column `a` start with `r` followed by five numbers.

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957890/pandas-select-from-dataframe-using-startswith) I learned how one would do this if it started just with `r` without the numbers:

```
print df.loc[df['a'].str.startswith('r'), :]

        a  b
1  r00001  1
2  r00010  2
3    rfoo  3
4  r01234  4
5   r1234  5
```

Something like this

```
print df.loc[df['a'].str.startswith(r'[r]\d{5}'), :]
```

does of course not work. How would one do this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**
*[`pd.Series.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match)*

```
df.a.str.match('^r\d{5}$')

1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Use it as a filter

```
df[df.a.str.match('^r\d{5}$')]

        a  b
1  r00001  1
2  r00010  2
4  r01234  4
```

---

**Option 2**
*Custom list comprehension using string methods*

```
f = lambda s: s.startswith('r') and (len(s) == 6) and s[1:].isdigit()
[f(s) for s in df.a.values.tolist()]

[False, True, True, False, True, False]
```

Use it as a filter

```
df[[f(s) for s in df.a.values.tolist()]]

        a  b
1  r00001  1
2  r00010  2
4  r01234  4
```

---

**Timing**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df[[s.startswith('r') and (len(s) == 6) and s[1:].isdigit() for s in df.a.values.tolist()]]
%timeit df[df.a.str.match('^r\d{5}$')]
%timeit df[df.a.str.contains('^r\d{5}$')]

10 loops, best of 3: 22.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 33.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 34.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: As `str.match` is using `re.match` the pattern could be changed to `'r\d{5}'` as by default it matches from the beginning of the string

Comment: I find it depressing to see list comprehension outperforming the supposed vectorised pandas methods, useful to add the timings

Comment: @EdChum Agreed!  I know the devs have a lot to do.  And I keep telling myself that when I can clear my schedule a bit, I'll start contributing to `pandas`... I still expect that I will at some point.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) and pass a regex pattern:

```
In[112]:
df.loc[df['a'].str.contains(r'^r\d{5}')]

Out[112]: 
        a  b
1  r00001  1
2  r00010  2
4  r01234  4
```

Here the pattern evaluates to `^r` - start with character r, and then `\d{5}` looks for 5 digits

`startswith` looks for a character pattern, not a regex pattern which is why it fails

Regarding the difference between [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) and [`str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match), they are analagous but `str.contains` uses `re.search` whilst `str.match` uses `re.match` which is more strict, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

**edit**

To answer your comment add `$` so that it matches a specific number of characters, see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590008/regular-expression-to-match-exact-number-of-characters):

```
In[117]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['abc', 'r000010', 'r00010', 'rfoo', 'r01234', 'r1234'], 'b': range(6)})
df

Out[117]: 
         a  b
0      abc  0
1  r000010  1
2   r00010  2
3     rfoo  3
4   r01234  4
5    r1234  5


In[118]:
df.loc[df['a'].str.match(r'r\d{5}$')]

Out[118]: 
        a  b
2  r00010  2
4  r01234  4
```

Comment: Not part of the original post, but how would one now exclude the ones that have more than 5 numbers (or any other characters)?

Comment: `r'^r\d{5}$` should handle this

Comment: Great, thanks, unfortunately, I cannot upvote twice. I accept the other answer as he was slightly faster but thanks for the detailed explanations.

Comment: Not an issue, glad I can help and add some explanations that are useful

Comment: @Cleb **1** I don't mean to speak for EdChum, but I'm fairly confident that he'd share my sentiment.  And that sentiment is, I know very well that his answer is every bit as good as mine and that you can only pick one... I'm ok with the outcome either way.  **2** I've added timings to my post, I have **zero** expectations that `match` would work any faster that `contains`.  My timings validate that.

Comment: @piRSquared rep isn't a big deal for me, attribution, quality of questions and answers is though. I think both answers contribute well to the question in different ways, I +1 your answer as soon as you posted it by the way

Comment: @piRSquared: By "faster" I meant that you answered slightly before EdChum; I was not referring to the performance of your respective solutions. When there is more than one answer I like, I usually accept the one that appeared first (and upvote every solution that answers my question in a reasonable way). And thanks for the timings; indeed surprising that list comprehensions are faster than the pandas solutions...

Comment: @Cleb I'd expect `match` to probably be slightly faster as by default it pattern matches from the beginning of the string so it's one less thing to worry about whilst `contains` is more general pattern matching anywhere in the string, you could say that `match` is semantically the correct thing to use here

Comment: @EdChum I was moments from clicking "save edits" when I saw your answer pop up, Since it was `contains`, I deleted my edit and upvoted instead.  *Oh* rep is a big deal for me at the moment... I want my mug and t-shirt (at least that is what I hope I get (-:)